# Remote connection to Debian container has a certain error (xrdp & sesman)

Tags: debian, docker, xfce, xrdp

I have created an image with a **Dockerfile** which is a **Debian Bookworm** that has the UI **XFCE** and where you connect **via xrdp** (remote desktop).

Let's get to the problem:

If I create a **whole new container** with this image, then **I can login** to the UI with RDP, **also log out** and **log in again**.
ONLY when I **restart** the container and want to log in again (on the **xrdp page**) then I get a sesman error (sesman is strangely not **active/started**).

But if i **start sesman** with `"/usr/sbin/xrdp-sesman"` everything works again **until** i **restart** the container.

Is this a logic error from my side? or is this a known problem with sesman.

***dockerfile:***

```
#use the debian bookworm image
FROM debian:bookworm

#update all package directories
RUN apt update

#install all needed programs like
#XFCE for UI
#xrdp for connecting via RemoteDesktop
#dbus-x11 for that you can connect to the desktop at all (otherwise the connection w>
#xfce4-goodies for the Xfce4 Desktop Environment (https://packages.debian.org/de/sid>
RUN apt install -y xrdp xfce4 dbus-x11

#install usefull tools like: nano, wget, curl and sudo
RUN apt install -y nano wget curl sudo

#FIX: removed the annoying screen "Plugin "Power Manager Plugin" unexpectedly left t>
RUN apt remove xfce4-power-manager-plugins -y

#clean up
RUN apt clean && apt autoremove -y

#create default user called "user", with password "changeme"
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash -p $(openssl passwd -1 changeme) user

#copy files
COPY /data/startScript.sh /

#make the start script runable
RUN chmod +x /startScript.sh

#expose the RDP port
EXPOSE 3389

#start the start script and run the container
CMD ["/startScript.sh"]
```

***startScript.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash

#start the xrdp session manager
/usr/sbin/xrdp-sesman

#start xrdp overall
/usr/sbin/xrdp -n
```

***User-Data:***

```
Username => user
Password => changeme
```

***CopyPaste-Commands:***

```
docker build -t debianxfcerdp .
docker run -d -p 3399:3389 --name test01 debianxfcerdp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem encountered with xrdp in the Docker container might be associated with how services are initiated and managed within the container. When the container restarts, it might fail to automatically trigger the xrdp-sesman service, resulting in connection failures. This could be the reason why manually starting sesman resolves the issue until the container is restarted.

One possible solution could involve reconfiguring the Docker container's entry point or startup script to ensure that essential services, such as xrdp-sesman, initiate upon container initialization. This might require managing it through a process manager or script within the container.

Adjustments to be made in the Dockerfile:

```
#copy the startup script into the container
COPY startScript.sh /usr/local/bin/startScript.sh

#grant execute permissions to the script
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/startScript.sh

# Set the script as entry point to run on container start
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/startScript.sh"]
```

Additionally, the startScript.sh has to be modify to properly initiate xrdp services:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Function to check and start the sesman service if not running
start_sesman() {
    if ! pgrep -x "xrdp-sesman" > /dev/null; then
        echo "xrdp-sesman not running. Starting sesman..."
        /usr/sbin/xrdp-sesman
    else
        echo "xrdp-sesman is already running."
    fi
}

# Start sesman
start_sesman

# Start xrdp
/usr/sbin/xrdp -n
```

This adjusted setup will initiate the startScript.sh as the container's entry point. It contains a function to verify if xrdp-sesman is running and starts it if it's not. This should ensure that the necessary services start upon container restart.